# pgfplots: coordinates from macros that change

Tags: pgfplots

I do realize that pgfplots needs to do its thing at `\end{axis}` apply scaling etc. But is there a manner where one can make this work as intended?

In the MWE I define a coordinate from a macro (my real life example is similar, but this should cover it), we draw a dot at the coordinate, change the macro, and draw again. On my system, I only get a single dot at (2,2).

Is there some sort of expansion trick that I'm not aware of to fix this?
(In my case I can just create the points a path intersections, but this should be faster)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmax=3,xmin=0,ymax=3,ymin=0
    ]
     \draw (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs:3,3);

     \def\Test{1}

     \coordinate (A) at (axis cs: \Test,\Test);

     \fill (A) circle (2pt);
     \def\Test{2}
     \fill (A) circle (2pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is probably to use this trick

```
\edef\temp{
    \noexpand\coordinate (A) at (axis cs: \Test,\Test);
}
\temp
```

which is also needed in other circumstances when dealing with the `axis` env.

Basically we ask to have the `\Test` macro expanded before the coordinate is defined, not when `axis` later typesets it.